# Why does this perl program with dynamic scoping print 1?

Tags: perl, dynamic, subroutine, scoping

Shouldn't this code print 2? After `q()` sub call in `r()`, the print should see the value changed by `q()`, but it doesn't.

```
sub p {
   local $x = 0;
   sub q {
        $x = 2;
   }

   sub r {
       local $x = 1;
       q();
       print($x);
   }

   local $x = 2;
   r(); 
}

p();
```

Comment: Could you make it any more convoluted...? :)  One key thing first: nested subs don't mean anything in Perl, other than unexpected behavior. So `sub p { ... sub q {...} ... };` is _wrong_.  Just pull out what you meant to "nest", `sub p { ... }; sub q { ... };` etc.  Then study what's going on... (If you absolutely insist of having it nested then look up "lexical subroutines," a newer feature.)

Comment: @zdim, Re "*Could you make it any more convoluted...?*", probably an assignment

Comment: I'm trying to replicate pseudocode for a university exam, and the only dynamic scoping language I found that I knew a bit was Perl. That's why the nested subroutines, I just copied an exercise that was written in pseudocode. When this is done with not-nested subs it works as expected.

Comment: OK.  You can get correct "nesting" behavior with [lexical subroutines](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Lexical-Subroutines) then.  Just prepend a `my` to its definition (or pre-declaration), `my sub subname {...};`  Then see what it does

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! Now it has the correct behavior.

Comment: Re "*When this is done with not-nested subs it works as expected.*", The nesting has absolutely no effect on the result.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should not have named subs inside of other named subs in Perl (except `my sub f { }`). It commonly leads to very weird behaviour. And there's no reason to do it; they are not scoped to the "parent" sub. (They can be called from outside the "parent" sub.) Thankfully, they don't cause any problem in this particular case.

On to the question. You might expect the value to be `2`. It's `1`, because `q()` doesn't mean what you think it means. `q()` is a single-quoted string literal. It's identical to `''`.  Had you enabled warnings, you would have gotten

```
Useless use of a constant ("") in void context
```

If we rename the subs, we get the expected result. The lack of repeated code makes this trivial to illustrate.

```perl
                           # order  $x before  $x after
                           # -----  ---------  --------
                           #     0                undef
sub ppp {                  #
   local $x = 0;           #     2      undef         0
                           #
   sub qqq {               #
        $x = 2;            #     7          1         2
                           #
   }                       #
                           #
   sub rrr {               #
       local $x = 1;       #     5          2         1
                           #
       qqq();              #     6          1         2
                           #
       print($x);          #     8          2         2
                           #
   }                       #     9          2         2 *
                           #
   local $x = 2;           #     3          0         2
                           #
   rrr();                  #     4          2         ?
}                          #    10          ?         0 *
                           #    11          0     undef *
                           #
ppp();                     #     1      undef     undef
```

* - These are a `local` restoring a previous value.